# Is there a way to use Google Location Sharing to send notifications to my phone?

Tags: android, api, geo-location, google-maps

Me and my boyfriend share our locations with each other. When he leaves the office and his location updates I'd like to get a notification to my phone that to notify me that he's on his way home. I guess I would need to make an Android app that uses Google Maps, but I don't think they have an API for location sharing. Does anyone know any other way I could get this information?

Comment: No need for Google Maps. What you are describing is called "geo-fencing" and implemented into many "child protection" apps: as soon as the "fenced area" is left, an alarm is sent. Which in your case would tell you your boyfriend has left the office (oops, but not if he's heading home – but for that you could define another geo-fence to get an alert when he's near). [More than 300 apps mention geofence](https://www.appbrain.com/search?q=geofence) – so for a good recommendation you might need to narrow things down ;)

Comment: Somewhat related to [my question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/61335/cross-platform-app-to-meet-my-friends-rendevous), but mine is more full-featured (and received no answers :-(